# Fill array with key-value values

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to fill an array with objects. If I execute setState, the new entry is not added but the structure of the array is extended. Example: Initial entry (0), new entry (0->0), another entry (0->0->0). I would like however for each entry a running numbering

```
const [entrys, setEntrys] = useState([{ date: "", entry: "" }]);
->click on button
setEntrys((prev) => [{ ...prev, date: clickedDay, entry: hinweis }]);
```

Comment: Spread `prev` into the array, not the new object - `[...prev, { date: clickedDay, entry: hinweis }]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that you have included the previous state, e.g. "prev" with the spread operator inside the object you are passing.

What you want to do is include the new object you are saving to state AND then include previous state, e.g. "prev" as a separate element in the array - like below.

I've included a codesandbox for you too https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-solomon-l566yy?file=/src/App.js.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [entries, setEntries] = useState([
    {
      date: "",
      text: ""
    }
  ]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setEntries((prevEntry) => {
      return [...prevEntry, { date: "date", text: "test" }];
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me!</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```